# previous text in label in tableview is displaying after reloading tableview

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a global declared array and loading that array in table view but when i go to other controller and update that array and reload table view again then text in labels in table view cell is overriding. Newer update data is overriding and previous also displaying in same label. here is my code:  Where item array is globally declared array.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
  }

UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 8, 100, 25)];
nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
nameLabel.text = [[itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"itemname"];
[cell addSubview:nameLabel];
[nameLabel release];

UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
deleteButton.frame= CGRectMake(3, 3, 30, 30);
[deleteButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell addSubview:deleteButton];


UILabel *priceMark = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 8, 65, 25)];
priceMark.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
priceMark.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
priceMark.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rs: %@",[[itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
objectForKey:@"amount"]];
[cell addSubview:priceMark];     
[priceMark release];

UILabel *qtyLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 8, 60, 25)];
qtyLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
qtyLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
qtyLabel.text = [[itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"qty"];
[cell addSubview:qtyLabel];
[qtyLabel release];

return cell;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

now i am getting other problem when i update item array that is globally declared at 0 index and return back then  it wont update the row in table view row at index 0 but when i update other rows then it updates. And also when i scroll table view towards upward then it shows value at index 0 on all index. here is my code

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
   *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 8, 100, 25)];
    nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16];
    [cell addSubview:nameLabel];

    deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    deleteButton.frame= CGRectMake(3, 3, 30, 30);
    [deleteButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:deleteButton];

    priceMark = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 8, 60, 25)]; //150, 8, 65, 25
    priceMark.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    priceMark.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
    [cell addSubview:priceMark]; 

    qtyLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 8, 65, 25)]; //225, 8, 60, 25
    qtyLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    qtyLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
    [cell addSubview:qtyLabel];
}


 nameLabel.text = [[itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"itemname"];
  priceMark.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rs: %@",[[itemsArray 
  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"amount"]];
   qtyLabel.text = [[itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"qty"];

return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create new UILabels and UIButtons and adding them as a subview every time.
Your problem here is that you add new ones every time.
You should make a custom UITableViewCell with labels and buttons and set them.

Comment: Nikola Kirev, I am facing the same issue, but few data is dynamic and have to add ImageView as per data.Then what should I do in this case?